# react router render component multiple times when refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to understand why when refreshing the page, the component is called multiple times:

**MainLayout.tsx: (routes component)**

```
import { FC, ReactElement, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import { IntroductionPage } from '../pages/introduction/introduction-page'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import { storage } from '../utils/storage'

export const history = createBrowserHistory()

export const MainLayout: FC = () => {
const { t } = useTranslation()

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('MainLayout:: constructor')
}, [])

const RequireAuth = (): ReactElement => {
  const { token } = storage.getState().authReducer
  let location = useLocation()
  if (!token) return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} />
  return <Outlet />
}

return (
  <BrowserRouter history={history}>
    <div className="main-wrapper">
      <div className="content-wrapper">
        <div className="main-content">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
              <Route path="/acceptance" element={<AcceptancePage />} />
              <Route path="/introduction/:page" element={<IntroductionPage />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
}
```

**introduction page**

I put the following code in introduction page:

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log('IntroductionPage:: constructor')
setIntroduction(introductions[+page - 1])
}, [])
```

I'm refreshing the introduction page, and see in the console:

```
IntroductionPage:: constructor
MainLayout.tsx:23 MainLayout:: constructor
IntroductionPage:: constructor
IntroductionPage:: constructor
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Are you having any state in your MainLayout? Please share the entire component so that its easy for others to answer

Comment: What's your react.js version?

Comment: "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-calendar": "^3.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.7",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.9.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.4.2",
    "react-fusioncharts": "^3.1.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.15.1",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-modal": "^3.14.4",
    "react-notifications": "^1.7.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-router-native": "^6.0.2",

Comment: React pretty much renders when it needs to render. It doesn't appear to be the case that your code is render looping so a double render here and there is likely React just computing what to render, or something changed in a parent component and that entire sub-ReactTree is rerendered.  Do you have an *actual* performance issue (i.e. one you've actually audited) that you are trying to fix? Is there an issue with the `IntroductionPage` component mounting twice? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see why the `IntroductionPage` component is mounted twice. The `RequireAuth` component is declared inside another React component. Since it is redeclared each render cycle it's a new React component reference so React unmounts the instance from the previous render cycle and mounts a new instance. All children it renders will also be new instances.

It should be declared out on its own, outside of any other React component.

Example:

```
const RequireAuth = (): ReactElement => {
  const { token } = storage.getState().authReducer;
  const location = useLocation();
  if (!token) return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} />;
  return <Outlet />;
};

export const MainLayout: FC = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('MainLayout:: constructor');
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter history={history}>
      <div className="main-wrapper">
        <div className="content-wrapper">
          <div className="main-content">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
              <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
                <Route path="/acceptance" element={<AcceptancePage />} />
                <Route path="/introduction/:page" element={<IntroductionPage />} />
              </Route>
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```